# Is there a difference between regex logic used in Oracle vs SQLLoader?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-loader

I have been trying to use regex_replace in sqlloader to parse out pieces of a string into two fields, ID_CLEAN_I and UNIT_I using the regex

```
^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\s]*$
```

to parse data into regex groups like this:

```
Example string: ABCD123456A
Group 1) ABCD
Group 3) 123456
Group 5) A
```

like so (you can think of :ID_I as ABCD123456A in this example) :

```
ID_CLEAN_I   EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\\s]*$', '\\1 \\3')",
UNIT_I    EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\\s]*$', '\\5')"
```

...and SQL-Loader never gets any matches, although if we test this in Oracle using a test string of ABCD123456A like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCD123456A', '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\s]*$', '\5')
FROM dual;
```

then we can get whatever matching group we want successfully (which is again primarily groups 1, 3, and 5).

SO, my question is for you SQL Loader/Oracle/Regex gurus - is there a difference between Oracle Regex and Regex used in SQL-Loader? If so, how would I need to change my Regex to make it more agreeable for loader?

EDIT, as requested, here are the specifics:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0,ERRORS=50,readsize=20971644,bindsize=20971520,ROWS=5000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Temp\text.txt'
BADFILE 'C:\Temp\text.BAD'
DISCARDFILE 'C:\Temp\text.DSC'
APPEND 
PRESERVE BLANKS
INTO MyTable
WHEN (some stuff happens)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    ID_I, -- this could be 'ABCD123456A' or 'ABCD  123456  A' or 'ABCD000123456A' 
    ID_CLEAN_I   EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\\s]*$', '\\1 \\3')", -- we want 'ABCD 123456'
    UNIT_I       EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\\s]*|[0]*| *)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\\s]*| *)([A-Za-z])[\\s]*$', '\\5')" -- we want 'A'
)

/*errors - note that UNIT_I can only be a single character  A, B, C, D...

Record 1: Rejected - Error on table MyTable, column UNIT_I.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "MyTable"."UNIT_I" (actual: 11, maximum: 1)

*/
```

Comment: Works for me through SQL\*Loader, in 11gR2 and with your sample value. Which database version are you using? And can you add the table definition and the whole control file to the question in case I'm doing something differently?

Comment: I can see some issues with your regex pattern; are you only seeing problems with values that have spaces in them? In addition to the info above, can you also add sample data that actually shows the behaviour you're asking about, and the data you end up with in your table when you load that data?

Comment: Thanks Alex, database is 11g and I will put in an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the square-bracket matching character list expressions incorrectly. `[\s]` will match the literal `\` or literal `s` characters, rather than any whitespace characters. As noted [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIEGEI):

> Matches any single character in the list within the brackets. In the list, all operators except these are treated as literals:
>
> Range operator: -
>   POSIX character class: [: :]
>   POSIX collation element: [. .]
>   POSIX character equivalence class: [= =]

To find whitespace using brackets you would need to use the character class, `[[:space:]]` instead. But you don't need to use character lists here, if the first check (i.e. the second group) is whitespace followed by zeros; you can use [the `\s` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDDGICJ), making your pattern more like:

```
'^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\s*)([A-Za-z])\s*$'
```

As a demo with a made-up value:

```
var id_i varchar2(20);
exec :id_i := 'ABC 012345 A ';

select REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\s*)([A-Za-z])\s*$', '\1 \3') as id_clean_i,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\s*)([A-Za-z])\s*$', '\5') as unit_i
from dual;

ID_CLEAN_I           UNIT_I             
-------------------- --------------------
ABC 12345            A
```

So your control file would have:

```
ID_I,
ID_CLEAN_I   EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\\s*)([A-Za-z])\\s*$', '\\1 \\3')",
UNIT_I       EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_REPLACE(:ID_I, '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\\s*)([A-Za-z])\\s*$', '\\5')"
```

The three sample values you added to the question all load with `ID_CLEAN_I` set to `'ABCD 123456'` and `UNIT_I` set to `'A'`.

Comment: Alex thanks for the response as it helped me identify the real problem in my data, which is what if there is no character at the end of the test string, say if we had 'ABCD123456'. In the end I found that ^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\s*0*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([A-Za-z]|\s*)$ worked well, now focusing on groups 1, 3, and 4.